# modify excel cells by using if - PHP -

Tags: php, excel, edit

```
<?php
require('Classes\PHPExcel.php');

$phpExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load('123.xlsx');
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($phpExcel, "Excel2007"); 
$sheet = $phpExcel ->getActiveSheet();

 $x=1;
 while ($x<=5){
     if($sheet->getCell('A'.$x)->getValue()=="1"){
     $sheet->SetCellValue('B'.$x, 'Something');
     }
 }
$writer->save('1234.xlsx');
?>
```

If I remove "while" and "if" lines... code is working perfectly and its getting completed in 1 second.
but this way, it can not complete process in 60 seconds and time over occurs.
123.xlsx has just A column and 5 numbers from 1 to 5. it is just for test but again its taking so long.
I still couldn't understand where im making mistake.

in normal 123.xlsx file will be around 800 rows and 20 columns, so it will take years :)

please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you incrementing the $i?

You might need to increment $i, based on your code requirement, you might increase $i in either while loop or inside if :

```
$x=1;
 while ($x<=5){
     if($sheet->getCell('A'.$x)->getValue()=="1")
     {
         $sheet->SetCellValue('B'.$x, 'Something');
         $x++;//Increment here?
     }
     $x++;//orIncrement here?
 }
```

Comment: @chandresh_cool Beware, it's `$x`, not `$i`. Good catch though `;)`

Comment: @roberto06 righly said. Typo :)

Comment: @ÇAğrıKeskin if this solved the question, consider accepting the answer. If you don't know how, it's the "gray" checkmark. When you tick it and it turns "green", it shows Stack/everyone that the question is solved and marked as closed.